# Mustache Templating adding condition

Tags: javascript, html, templates, module, mustache

Hello Im new to modular javascript programming and templating
and Im builiding templates out of my previous code of a slideShow module

The code is like

```
<section id="slideShow">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="..." alt="">
            <a href="...">
                <h1 class="slideShowTitle">...</h1>
                <p class="slideShowDate">...</p>
                <p class="slideShowDetail">...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="..." alt="">
            <a href="...">
                <h1 class="slideShowTitle">...</h1>
                <p class="slideShowDate">...</p>
                <p class="slideShowDetail">...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="noDetail noLink">
            <img src="..." alt="">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <h1 class="slideShowTitle">...</h1>
                <p class="slideShowDate">...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="noDetail noLink">
            <img src="..." alt="">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <h1 class="slideShowTitle">...</h1>
                <p class="slideShowDate">...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="noDetail">
            <img src="..." alt="">
            <a href="...">
                <h1 class="slideShowTitle">...</h1>
                <p class="slideShowDate">...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

now Im searching for this like couple of hours now

I wrote something like this

```
<section id="slideShow">
    <ul>
        <script id="slideShowTemplate" type="text/template">
            {{#slideShow}}
                <li class="">
                    <img src="{{.}}" alt="">
                    <a href="{{.}}">
                        <h1 class="slideShowTitle">{{.}}</h1>
                        <p class="slideShowDate">{{.}}</p>
                        {{#slideShowDetail}}
                            <p class="slideShowDetail">{{.}}</p>
                        {{/slideShowDetail}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {{/slideShow}}
        </script>
    </ul>
</section>
```

my main problem is
as you see **some list elements (li) have p.slideShowDetail inside and some dont**
the ones that dont have this class **the parent li has class "noDetail"**

and I put

```
{{#slideShowDetail}}
    <p class="slideShowDetail">{{.}}</p>
{{/slideShowDetail}}
```

to make it work

now the problem is I want to say if there is no slideShowDetail for that particular slide I want the parent li had the class "noDetail"

also for **some slides the a href is an address and for some it is "javascript:void(0)** which means that slide is no clickable

now I want somehow put this **condition into my code that if the slideShow Object array doesnt have any value for the link the href become "javascript:void"**
and I want do this in **my HTML side** rather than a **condition on the js side**

AND

**if that slide doesnt have any link the parent li had the class name "noLink" as well**

so its kinda like Bottom to Top condition

Ive searched alot for this and didnt find any thing
I started to doubt maybe Im using the wrong template system or methodology

Appreciate your help

**UPDATE**

```
{{#slideShow}}
    <li class="{{^self.link"}}noLink{{^self.link"}} {{^self.detail"}}noDetail{{^self.detail}}">
        <img src="{{.}}" alt="">
        <a href="{{^self.link}} ? {{.}} : javascript:void(0)">
            <h1 class="slideShowTitle">{{.}}</h1>
            <p class="slideShowDate">{{.}}</p>
            {{#self.detail}}
                <p class="slideShowDetail">{{.}}</p>
            {{/self.detail}}
        </a>
    </li>
{{/slideShow}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mustache is a perfect template engine, use it to do the rendering of your page and keep the main logic in your controller.

**this way you could have all the data set on your controller and have a json already setted for your template like for example:**

```
{
    "slideShow": [
        {
            "slideClass":"noLink noDetail",
            "slideImageUrl":"http://myImage1",
            "slideAction":"javascript:void(0)",
            "slideTitle":"slide1",
            "slideDate": "30/11/2018",
            details: [
                { "detail": "detail1" },
                { "detail": "detail2" },
                { "detail": "detail3" }
            ]           
        },
        {
            "slideClass":"",
            "slideImageUrl":"http://myImage2",
            "slideAction":"doAction();",
            "slideTitle":"slide2",
            "slideDate": "30/11/2018",
            details: [
                { "detail": "detail1" },
                { "detail": "detail2" },
                { "detail": "detail3" }
            ]           
        }   
    ]
}
```

**And use your template like this:**

```
{{#slideShow}}
    <li class="{{slideClass"}}">
        <img src="{{slideImageUrl"}}" alt="">
        <a href="{{slideAction}}">
            <h1 class="slideShowTitle">{{slideTitle}}</h1>
            <p class="slideShowDate">{{slideDate}}</p>
            {{#details}}
                <p class="slideShowDetail">{{.}}</p>
            {{/details}}
        </a>
    </li>
{{/slideShow}}
```

**In other hand, the negation condition work like this**

```
{
    "slideShow": [
    ]
}
```

And your template

```
{{^slideShow}}
    <li>
       some html code
    </li>
{{/slideShow}}
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering, would you please read my UPDATE and see if I can use condition inside tag attribute, this way I can avoid adding class on the data layer and the app will detect which kind of class should give to the li

Comment: You're welcome, i read the mustache documentation http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html
there is no way to do what you're trying to do. Base on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines 
The engine is not able to proceed such evaluation.
You may look for an other solution.

Comment: and is there any better template engine which makes me to do that ?

Comment: For sure you will find a benchmark of the template engines on my previous comment. What is your application code with? Java? Js? Php...?

Comment: php, because the templating is a new concept to me, I may not fully understand their different features compared to eachother

Comment: For php one of the best template engine is Smarty: https://www.smarty.net/
And good news you will be able to do logical tests right away in the template side.